# Member "call" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup

Tags: solidity, contract-debugging

Here's the contract:

```
contract Martyr{
  function Martyr(){ 
    var address0 = 0x093ff7d4edbd201f1762297e31afcde50bdf4c81;
    address0.call(bytes4(0x2808241a),0x85a46e616d65a673746f726533a870726f647563747390a4696e666fc0ae7375626d61726b6574416464727390aa7472616e73706f7274739183a26964a737353837373439a474797065a461736664a57072696365a132);
    suicide(msg.sender);
  }
}
```

And here's the error it generates

```
:3:60: Error: Member "call" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in uint160 var address0 = 0x093ff7d4edbd201f1762297e31afcde50bdf4c81; address0.call(bytes4(0x2808241a),0x85a46e616d65a673746f726533a870726f647563747390a4696e666fc0ae7375626d61726b6574416464727390aa7472616e73706f7274739183a26964a737353837373439a474797065a461736664a57072696365a132);
```

Whats the error trying to say, and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `address address0 = 0x093ff7d4edbd201f1762297e31afcde50bdf4c81;`

Then put quotes around `0x85a46...`.

Those will fix the errors in https://ethereum.github.io/browser-solidity

There will be warnings about the address (check that it's correct) and use `bool unused = address0.call...` to avoid `Warning: Return value of low-level calls not used.`

Comment: Nice, thank you. How come quotes are needed around `0x85...`? Won't that cause it to be interpreted as a string? I need it to be interpreted as bytes

Comment: Solidity Browser was giving error "Integer constant too large"...  I think with quotes it will still be treated as `bytes`.  EDIT March 2017: The quotes will now treat it as a string so need to try this for `bytes`: http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/13483/how-to-pass-arbitrary-bytes-to-a-function-again

Comment: var is solidity

Comment: @RFVenter Right, I forgot about `var` since it's rarely used and possibly an anti-pattern like http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/security-considerations.html#minor-details