# How to pass arbitrary bytes to a function in Remix (2017)

Tags: solidity, remix, bytes

According to [this question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2616/how-to-pass-arbitrary-bytes-to-a-function) I could write a simple contract like:

```
contract SimpleStorage {
  bytes input;
  function setInput(bytes enterBytes){
    input = enterBytes;
  }
}
```

Using "0x1234" as a parameter in Remix "does not work" and stores "0x307831323334" in the storage array. If I change the code to `bytes2` then everything works as intended with the same command. How can I do the same using a dynamic array?

```
contract SimpleStorage {
  bytes2 input;
  function setInput(bytes2 enterBytes){
    input = enterBytes;
  }
}
```

Comment: I think input and output of functions should be consistent in remix. Hence I submitted this issue: https://github.com/ethereum/remix/issues/496

Answer (score 30, accepted):

1. You can pass bytes parameters in Remix or browser-solidity as the array of single bytes, for example **["0x00","0xaa", "0xff"]** is equivalent to  **"0x00aaff"**
2. Do not know why, but the Remix IDE and browser-solidity interprets "0xaabb11..." as string. For development and testing purpose on private or test net you can use the code below. Function **hexStrToBytes** will do the conversion. You can use its result, as it is demonstrated in setInputFromHex function

code:

```
contract SimpleStorage 
{
    bytes input;

    function setInput(bytes enterBytes){
        input = enterBytes;
    }

    function getInput()
    returns (bytes)
    {
        return input;
    }

    function setInputFromHex(string hex_str)
    {
        input = hexStrToBytes(hex_str);
    }

    function hexStrToBytes(string hex_str) constant
    returns (bytes)
    {
        //Check hex string is valid
        if (bytes(hex_str)[0]!='0' ||
            bytes(hex_str)[1]!='x' ||
            bytes(hex_str).length%2!=0 ||
            bytes(hex_str).length<4)
            {
                throw;
            }

        bytes memory bytes_array = new bytes((bytes(hex_str).length-2)/2);

        for (uint i=2;i<bytes(hex_str).length;i+=2)
        {
            uint tetrad1=16;
            uint tetrad2=16;

            //left digit
            if (uint(bytes(hex_str)[i])>=48 &&uint(bytes(hex_str)[i])<=57)
                tetrad1=uint(bytes(hex_str)[i])-48;

            //right digit
            if (uint(bytes(hex_str)[i+1])>=48 &&uint(bytes(hex_str)[i+1])<=57)
                tetrad2=uint(bytes(hex_str)[i+1])-48;

            //left A->F
            if (uint(bytes(hex_str)[i])>=65 &&uint(bytes(hex_str)[i])<=70)
                tetrad1=uint(bytes(hex_str)[i])-65+10;

            //right A->F
            if (uint(bytes(hex_str)[i+1])>=65 &&uint(bytes(hex_str)[i+1])<=70)
                tetrad2=uint(bytes(hex_str)[i+1])-65+10;

            //left a->f
            if (uint(bytes(hex_str)[i])>=97 &&uint(bytes(hex_str)[i])<=102)
                tetrad1=uint(bytes(hex_str)[i])-97+10;

            //right a->f
            if (uint(bytes(hex_str)[i+1])>=97 &&uint(bytes(hex_str)[i+1])<=102)
                tetrad2=uint(bytes(hex_str)[i+1])-97+10;

            //Check all symbols are allowed
            if (tetrad1==16 || tetrad2==16)
                throw;

            bytes_array[i/2-1]=byte(16*tetrad1+tetrad2);
        }

        return bytes_array;
    }
}
```

Comment: This just sort of hangs saying "waiting to be mined". It might be that my bytes string is too long

Comment: @ZMitton if you need to store something to blockchain, for example when you execute **setInputFromHex**, you need mining process. It is not the problem of this contract - it is rule. If you work on your own node - start mining. Function **hexStrToBytes** does not need mining process (already, code was edited).

Comment: I awarded the bounty based on solution 1. This solves the issue of inputting bytes from remix/browser-solidity. Thank you

Comment: @ZMitton Could you please mark answer as "answered"

Comment: If anyone needs a quick way to do this for debugging I made this little util to make it faster: [random bytes generator for remix](https://1024web.netlify.com)

Answer (score 4):

let us consider i have function whose input parameter is

```
bytes32

bytes32[ ] // array of type bytes 32

uint8
```

which looks like:

```
 function abc(bytes32 id, bytes32[ ] name,uint8 version) returns(bool)
    {  
        //
    }
```

so now,to provoke the function (using remix) you have to pass parameters which looks like:

```
"0x12",["0x1262","0x12","0x12"],8
```

Comment: But when we call that function from inside the contract. Then can we pass " " in the bytes field?????

Comment: I'm puzzled by the fact I can't pass a bytes[]  to remix. I've tried everything, including what you suggest above.