# contract address returning as null value

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum

I am trying to create a factory contract and storing the smart contract address in an array but when I trying to retrieve the value, it always gives null value. Please find the contracts that I have used below.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.7;

contract ContractTest {
    bytes32 public Name;

    function ContractTest (bytes32 name) {
        Name = name;
    }
}


pragma solidity ^0.4.7;
import './ContractTest.sol';

contract FactoryTest{
    address[2] newContracts;

    function createContract (bytes32 name) {
        address newContract = new ContractTest(name);
        newContracts[0]=newContract;
    }
        function getContract() returns(address) {
          return newContracts[0];
        }
}
```

Comment: Refer the following link to pass bytes arguments to a function in remix https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/13483/how-to-pass-arbitrary-bytes-to-a-function-in-remix/13658

Answer (score 1):

With a bit of refactoring and reformatting, I ended up with this code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.7;

contract ContractTest { 
    string public Name;

    function ContractTest (string name) {
        Name = name;
    }
}

contract FactoryTest { 
    address[2] newContracts;

    function createContract (string name) {
        address newContract = new ContractTest(name);
        newContracts[0]=newContract;
    }

    function getContract() returns(address) {
      return newContracts[0];
    }
}
```

The only real change is the use of `string` instead of `bytes`. I was testing it in Remix and I couldn't get it to accept input as `bytes` so I changed the input type.

The code above works just fine. So either the problem is somehow with the `bytes`  or then you are testing it wrong.

Comment: Hi Lauri, It is working in remix but not working in geth .Could you please try this in ethereum private network. I was trying this in local ethereum network with geth.

Comment: I don't have private network (Ganache) available right here now and unfortunately I will probably forget to test this the next time I have it available.

Comment: Anyway, it shouldn't make a difference. The result should be the same.

Comment: Unfortunately for me the result is coming as null value

Answer (score 0):

How are you calling `getContract`? From solidity or javascript.

The function `getContract` is not declared as view, for example if you call it from js it will execute it as a transaction and will not return the value you are expecting.

```
contract FactoryTest { 
    address[2] newContracts;

    function createContract(string name) public {
        address newContract = new ContractTest(name);
        newContracts[0] = newContract;
    }

    function getContract() public view returns (address) {
      return newContracts[0];
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Ismael   I have tried the same and I was getting address via remix (connected via web3 provider to local geth. But when I tried the same via geth its not returning the address.                                                         
 contract = eth.contract(JSON.parse(abiData))
contractObj = contract.new({from: eth.accounts[0], data: binData, gas: 2000000 })
ContractInst = contract.at(“Contract Address”)

ContractInst.createContract.sendTransaction("test",{from: eth.accounts[0], gas: 100000})

ContractInst.getContract.call() returns  0x000000000000000

Comment: issue got resolved . the amount of gas was given was not sufficient