# Remix - Pass bytesX to function

Tags: solidity, remix, bytes

Using Remix, I can't pass a set of bytes `["0xee", "0xff", "0xgg", "0xhh", "0xii"]` to my function

```
function foo(bytes5 input) {
    // Do something
}
```

I've already tried all these formats:

```
["0xee", "0xff", "0xgg", "0xhh", "0xii"]
["0xeeffgghhii"]
["0xee0xff0xgg0xhh0xii"]
"0xeeffgghhii"
"0xee0xff0xgg0xhh0xii"
[["0xee"], ["0xff"], ["0xgg"], ["0xhh"], ["0xii"]]
"0xee", "0xff", "0xgg", "0xhh", "0xii"
```

The IDE always raises the same error or says (legitimately) that the number of arguments doesn't match with my function:

> Error encoding arguments: Error: invalid bytes5 value (arg="", type="object", value=undefined)

As you can see I already tried the solutions suggested [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/13483/how-to-pass-arbitrary-bytes-to-a-function-in-remix) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50282211/solidity-remix-passing-multiple-bytes32-type-arguments), how should I do it? 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set of bytes must be in hex, `0xgg`, `0xhh` and `0xii` are not hex bytes.

Try this:

```
input : ["0xee", "0xff", "0xff", "0xff"]

function foo(bytes5 input) public view returns (bytes5) {
    return input;
}

output: 0: bytes5: 0xeeffffff00
```

If you want something more arbitrary:

```
input :  ["0x00","0xaa", "0xff"]

function foo(bytes memory input) public view returns (bytes memory) {
    return input;
}

output:  0: bytes: 0x00aaff
```

Comment: Damn I spent half an hour on this silly mistake! Thank you very much!